# Install a free documentation software like Confluence/Trac on Google Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, wiki, trac

I'd like to install a documentation software for technical and non technical reports on my google cloud environment.
A DokuWiki prebuilt package is installable from the launcher but is not free.
Does anybody know how to install a free documentation software like Trac (but also other solutions are well accepted) on an app engine? Or maybe within a container?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/trac) provides containers and installers for the cloud.

Comment: DokuWIki and Trac have no "usage fee"  via the Bitnami launchers. The price it quotes is the cost of the GCE instance and disk. However if you stay within the [free tier limits](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/always-free-usage-limits#compute_name) you won't pay that.